# Yii -- Invalid argument foreach()

Tags: php, yii

I have developed Yii application on Ubuntu. After this I committed the project and reinstalled OS to windows 8.I install "XAMPP" with PHP Version 5.4.22. So, my application is not running on the new server. I have Yii version 1.1.13 and I'm getting this error :

```
    Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

    C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\Yii_1.1.13\framework\base\CModule.php(191)
        public function setParams($value)
189     {
190         $params=$this->getParams();
191         foreach($value as $k=>$v)
192             $params->add($k,$v);
193     }
```

config array

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/main.php'),
    array(
        'name'=>'Store Space Local',
        'serverName'=>'storespace.loc',
        'components'=>array(
            'db'=>array(
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=storespace',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'tablePrefix'=>'ss_',
                'enableProfiling'=>true,
                'enableParamLogging'=>true,
                'schemaCachingDuration'=>1000
            ),
            'log'=>array(
                'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                'routes'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
                        'levels'=>'profile',
                        'enabled'=>true,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'cache'=>array(
                'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
//              'class'=>'system.caching.CApcCache',
//              'class'=>'system.caching.CDummyCache',
                /*'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
                            'servers'=>array(
                                array('host'=>'localhost', 'port'=>11211),

                            ),*/

            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

print_r of array

```
Array
(
    [basePath] => C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\protected\config\..
    [name] => Store Space Local
    [theme] => storespace
    [sourceLanguage] => en
    [language] => en
    [aliases] => Array
        (
            [dashboard] => C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\protected\config/../modules/dashboard
            [admin] => C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\protected\config/../modules/admin
            [manager] => C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\protected\config/../modules/manager
            [store] => C:\xampp\htdocs\storespace.loc\protected\config/../modules/store
        )

    [preload] => Array
        (
            [0] => log
            [1] => bootstrap
        )

    [import] => Array
        (
            [0] => application.models.*
            [1] => application.components.*
            [2] => application.behaviors.*
            [3] => application.helpers.*
            [4] => application.validators.*
            [5] => application.widgets.*
            [6] => application.extensions.yii-mail.*
            [7] => application.extensions.image.*
            [8] => application.extensions.config.*
            [9] => ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap
            [10] => ext.bootstrap.widgets.*
            [11] => ext.payments.models.*
        )

    [controllerNamespace] => \application\controllers
    [behaviors] => Array
        (
            [start] => Array
                (
                    [class] => application\behaviors\StartBehavior
                )

        )

    [modules] => Array
        (
            [gii] => Array
                (
                    [class] => system.gii.GiiModule
                    [password] => 123456
                    [ipFilters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 127.0.0.1
                            [1] => ::1
                        )

                    [generatorPaths] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => bootstrap.gii
                        )

                )

            [dashboard] => Array
                (
                    [class] => \dashboard\DashboardModule
                )

            [admin] => Array
                (
                    [class] => \admin\AdminModule
                )

            [manager] => Array
                (
                    [class] => \manager\StoreManagerModule
                )

            [store] => Array
                (
                    [class] => \store\StoreModule
                )

        )

    [components] => Array
        (
            [bootstrap] => Array
                (
                    [class] => application\components\Bootstrap
                    [responsiveCss] => 1
                )

            [cfg] => Array
                (
                    [class] => ext\config\DbConfig
                    [table] => {{config}}
                    [cacheId] => SITE_CONFIG
                )

            [similar] => Array
                (
                    [class] => ext\similar\PhpCalculator
                )

            [actorsRating] => Array
                (
                    [class] => \application\components\ActorsRating
                )

            [image] => Array
                (
                    [class] => CImageComponent
                    [driver] => GD
                )

            [mailFactory] => Array
                (
                    [class] => application\components\MailFactory
                )

            [mail] => Array
                (
                    [class] => YiiMail
                    [transportType] => php
                    [viewPath] => application.views.mail
                    [layoutName] => main
                )

            [stringHelper] => Array
                (
                    [class] => StringHelper
                )

            [user] => Array
                (
                    [class] => application\components\WebUser
                    [allowAutoLogin] => 1
                    [loginUrl] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => dashboard/user/login
                        )

                )

            [urlManager] => Array
                (
                    [class] => ext\languages\UrlManager
                    [urlSuffix] => /
                    [urlFormat] => path
                    [showScriptName] => 
                    [rules] => Array
                        (
                            [/] => /site/index
                            [/site] => /site/index
                            [/login/] => /dashboard/user/login
                            [login/] => /dashboard/user/login
                            [/get-trial/] => /dashboard/user/trial
                            [get-trial/] => /dashboard/user/trial
                            [/register//] => /dashboard/user/register
                            [register//] => /dashboard/user/register
                            [/pay//] => /dashboard/payment/pay
                            [pay//] => /dashboard/payment/pay
                            [/article/-] => /article/view
                            [article/-] => /article/view
                            [/contact-us] => /site/contactUs
                            [contact-us] => /site/contactUs
                            [/] => 
                            [/] => /index
                            [//] => /
                            [///] => //
                        )

                )

            [errorHandler] => Array
                (
                    [errorAction] => /site/error
                )

            [log] => Array
                (
                    [class] => CLogRouter
                    [routes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => CFileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => error, warning
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => \application\components\FileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => ipn
                                    [logFile] => ipn.log
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => \application\components\FileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => recurring-response
                                    [logFile] => recurring-response.log
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => \application\components\FileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => info
                                    [logFile] => info.log
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => \application\components\FileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => dibs
                                    [logFile] => dibs.log
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => CProfileLogRoute
                                    [levels] => profile
                                    [enabled] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [clientScript] => Array
                (
                    [scriptMap] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [session] => Array
                (
                    [autoStart] => 1
                )

            [authManager] => Array
                (
                    [class] => application\components\PhpAuthManager
                )

            [db] => Array
                (
                    [connectionString] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=storespace
                    [username] => root
                    [password] => 
                    [charset] => utf8
                    [tablePrefix] => ss_
                    [enableProfiling] => 1
                    [enableParamLogging] => 1
                    [schemaCachingDuration] => 1000
                )

            [cache] => Array
                (
                    [class] => system.caching.CFileCache
                )

        )

    [params] => 1
    [serverName] => storespace.loc
)
```

What way i can use for solution this trouble? 
Thanks!

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Comment: the array that you want to use in `foreach` is empty,or its not array.
 try `print_r($array_that_you_want_to_iterate)` and put the result in your question .

Comment: and what is your code for `foreach` ?

Comment: This is not my code, this is Yii code. And errors in framework. I think this is conflict in version php, but i am don't know why

Comment: This error can be a real pain if you have not recently made a change you can track this error to.

Comment: I am added print_r of array may be this will help. Help me please, guys! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Arthur, can you please update the question with the complete stack trace?  The array you posted is (obviously) an array, so my guess is that a careful review of the trace will lead you to some place where an empty/false/null value is being passed somewhere where it shouldn't.  The detailed stack traces are one of my favorite things about Yii =)

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, tomorrow i will do it!

Comment: $value is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `print_r` of the array the value of `params` is `1` which is invalid. Yii expects that to be an array. If you don't want to have any parameters then set it to `array()`.

Comment: I am a little don't understand, can you please explain what i will can do?

Comment: Your config array has an index `params`. It is not in the file you showed so it must be in `dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/main.php'`. Open that file and set `params` to an array value. e.g. `params => array()`.

Comment: There are return array(...) and we are use CMap::mergeArray(array(),array()) and so before its work on ubuntu.